# How to change the 3D Mesh resolution?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I need to fix the resolution of the mesh lines drawn on some surfaces, and currently I don't know how.  Here's a MWE to work with (a simple sphere) :

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t] Cos[p], Sin[t] Sin[p], Cos[t]},
{t, 0, Pi}, {p, 0, 2 Pi},
Boxed -> False,
Axes -> None, 
ImageSize -> {500, 500},
PlotPoints -> {7, 7},
Mesh -> {3, 7},
SphericalRegion -> True]
```

If you rotate around this ball, you'll notice that the three circular mesh curves don't have a nice and regular polygonal shape around the ball.  The polygons are irregular, and it's ugly.

How can I make the black mesh lines to look more regular, without changing the **PlotPoints** ?  Or what combination of **PlotPoints** and **Mesh** (plus some other commands ?) would make the nicest plot, i.e. regular mesh curves everywhere ?

Comment: One of the mesh lines seems to be "missing" in the result of your code as well: see the bottom left corner of [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bmokn.png).

Comment: Yes, there's a line missing.  The only way I know to add its black line is to add **BoundaryStyle -> Automatic**.  I think it's because of some hidden boundary between **phi = 0** and **phi = 2Pi**.

Comment: @Cham Do you consider the result with `Mesh->All` to be a good one?

Comment: Increasing PlotPoints (try 20) works well in combination with MaxRecursion (try 3).

Answer (score 1):

This work around seems to give good results. We specify both (i) mesh lines and (ii) a slightly redundant range for `p`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t] Cos[p], Sin[t] Sin[p], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 
  Pi}, {p, 0, 201/100 Pi}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, 
 ImageSize -> {500, 500}, Mesh -> {10, Range[0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/12]},
  SphericalRegion -> True]
```

[image]

Without the mesh lines or the range redundancy we get less regular lines. For example:

[image]